# How can i make this box align at center in css?

Tags: html, css

```css
.dkk {
 color:white;
 margin: 0px auto;
 text-align: center;
 display:inline-block;
 border: 3px solid;
 padding:10px;
 background-color:#333333;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="dkk">We are currently under construction.</h2>
```

This is the box. If I can know how to make this one, i can do others myself.

Comment: This is my first time to try coding and using this website, you can ask me any information need to make job easier.

Answer (score 0):

add `display:block` in your css, it will work's

```css
.dkk {
 color:white;
 margin: 0px auto;
 text-align: center;
 border: 3px solid;
 padding:10px;
 background-color:#333333;
        display:block;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="dkk">We are currently under construction.</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace:

```
display: inline-block;
```

With :

```
display: block;
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/terza_terza/rLnz01xc/